# Objective-C++ can't use vector push_back within enumerate block

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

### bar.mm

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

+ (BOOL)addURIs:(NSArray<NSString *>*)URIs {
    std::vector<std::string> uris;
    uris.push_back("1234");    // works!

    [URIs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        std::string str = std::string([obj UTF8String]);
        uris.push_back(str); // error: No matching member function for call to 'push_back'
    }];
    return YES;
}
```

I've currently using objective-c++ to bridge a C++ library to Objecitve-C.

I created a vector contains string and attempt to push_back another string.

Why the first `push_back` success and the second `push_back` comes up with error?

```
No matching member function for call to 'push_back'
```

### Edit:

```
std::vector<std::string> *vector = {};
[URIs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    std::string str = std::string([obj UTF8String]);
    vector->push_back(str);
}];
```

Using a pointer seems like to be a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks capture local C++ variables by copying them with the copy constructor, and then they are const in the block [See Reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html)

> Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope are captured as const variables.
>
> ...
>
> If you use any other C++ stack-based object from within a block, it
>   must have a const copy constructor. The C++ object is then copied
>   using that constructor.

This means that inside the block you can only call methods of the `uris` vector which are marked const (such as `size()`).

You can use the `__block` storage specifier to allow the variable to be modified within the block.

```
// this will allow it to be modified within capturing blocks
__block std::vector<std::string> uris;
```

You could also just iterate the array with a loop, rather than a block.

Comment: Ah, good point. By the way, using a pointer seems like to be a workaround? See my edit above.

Comment: @ZigiiWong yes, a pointer would be marked const, but that still allows you to modify the instance it points to (just not reassign the pointer). I would prefer `__block` to pointer so you don't have to change to pointer syntax depending on where the code is placed.